# Partitioning a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, partitioning

I have a large table of the following format called "SourceTable".

[image]

I also have a "TargetTable" having the same structure. This table is partitioned over the "AuditDate" column

Now, I need to write a stored procedure which takes only one input, the "AuditDate" and performs the following:

1. Check if the respective partition is already present in the target    table. If not, create one new partition. If already present, delete    the record from that partition.
2. Then load the data from source    table to target table for that Audit Date.

I know how to use a wizard for partitioning, but I am not being able to do this.

Comment: No responses from anyone, when I need it the most?? Everyone busy on Christmas??

Comment: No, we don't have enterprise version. We use triggers and view partitioning instead. But try: http://sqlmag.com/database-administration/how-dynamically-create-and-maintain-table-partitions